# Capitalization of Adjective from Proper Noun

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As the title of a piece of music, I am trying to translate the words 'Oedipal Eucharist' into Latin, with appropriate capitalization. I have:

Eucharistia oedipal

1. Am I correct that it is 'Eucharistia' and not 'Eucharistica'?
2. Am I correct that as a Latin adjective, the word 'oedipal' needs to appear without a capital 'O' ([i ]even though this is the title of a piece of music, and [ii] as in the way that in French, the adjective 'français' appears with a lower-case 'f'.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 6):

1. [You are correct](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Deucharistia).
2. There is no word *oedipal* in Latin. If you want an adjective from Oedipus' name, you would use *Oedipodionia*. It is in fact customary to capitalize adjectives derived from proper nouns, as editors [regularly do for this word](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=oedipodionia).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive and helpful answer CMW. Eucharistia Oedipodionia

Comment: @user13828 If you find that this answers your question completely, remember to click on the green tick to mark it completed. Happy to help!